# How to install virtualbox on Antergos

Tags: virtualbox, antergos, dkms

I'm trying to run Virutalbox on Antergos but I'm getting this following error

```
Kernel driver not install
```

Error
[image]

shell
[image]

I installed VirtualBox via the Archlinux Package Manager

Comment: you need to reboot your machine, your current kernel is 4.12.6 and your installed kernel is 4.12.8... try again after rebooting

Comment: thanks @ChristopherDíazRiveros it works! you could add an answer so that I can vote it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the modules here is the running kernel.

`uname -r` shows

`4.12.6-1`

and the installed kernel is

`4.12.8-2` so given the update, some modules have been erased from the system and it is necessary to reload them, the easiest way is to restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall kernel headers package 
Or you need to add the modules names to /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf

These are the module names:

vboxdrv vbonetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci